# Qt - QGraphicsScene is overlapping images

Tags: c++, qt, blur, qgraphicsscene

So I was following this tutorial, https://deadbird.fr/?p=800, to obtain blur behind windows in qt.. Made some changes like request a capture() when a resize event is scheduled and added a timer to update every 200ms the image with QTimer so when for example a window is minimized the background image is updated. So far so good..

But then I tested the timer and I noticed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WixIShA48jg
As you can see in the sixth second of the video the QGraphicsScene is overlapping the images, even with scene->clear();

The other problem I have is the color. I changed the background color of the dialog to blue but only the borders are blue. I also tried to put the QGraphicsView in a QFrame with transparency and blue color but no luck. Why is that?

You can find the source code in the tutorial site. My changes are visible in the video. The video is also in 720p.

Comment: Why not to ask the author of the code? He may know about this behaviour.

Comment: Could you post a link to your source code? Thx ;)

Comment: @deadbird My changes of the code are visible in the video.